# Custom logging verbosity for Actioncable process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, actioncable

I have the following Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rails s -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV Puma
action_cable: bundle exec puma -p $ACTIONCABLE_PORT cable/config.ru
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq
```

Both the `action_cable` process and the `web` rails process use $RAILS_ENV variables exported via .bashrc variables, setting which environment rails boots. So, running foreman start loads test environments for both `action_cable` and `web`. However, I want actioncable to use `:info` Log Level and I want web rails process to use `fatal`.

Is there a way I can bootup both processes and use ENV or process information to dynamically set the log level?

Something like (pseudo code):

```
# environments/test.rb
config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT))
if Process.port == 28080
  config.log_level = :info
  Sidekiq::Logging.logger.level = Logger::INFO
else
  config.log_level = :fatal
  Sidekiq::Logging.logger.level = Logger::FATAL
end
```